# Cравнение элементов двумерной матрицы Python

Tags: python, numpy, матрицы

следующий вопрос: как в python с NumPy пройтись по каждому элементу двумерной матрицы, сравнив его с каким-то значением? Мой код выглядит так:

```
print("Укажите размер массива, столбцов:")
n = int(input())
print("Укажите размер массива, строк:")
m = int(input())
universe = np.random.randint(2, size=(m, n))
print (universe)
for row in universe:
      for x in row:
          if universe[[row], [x]] == 1:
              j += 1
print (j)
```

В моем случае выводит ошибку:

```
if universe[[row], [x]] == 1:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать правильно, спасибо.

Comment: Вам нужно что-то такое https://stackoverflow.com/a/10998027/7485582

Comment: Я вернул предыдущую версию вашего вопроса, т.к на него уже ответили. Когда вы хотите что-то другое, задайте другой вопрос, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо

```
for row in universe:
      for x in row:
          if universe[[row], [x]] == 1:
```

примените

```
for row in range(universe.shape[0]):
    for x in range(universe.shape[1]):
        if universe[row, x] == 1:
```

Answer (score 0):

Сравнить можно так:

```
universe == 1
```

В результате получится массив того же размера, содержащий значения типа bool, обозначающие выполнение или невыполнение условия.

Подсчитать количество вхождений можно так:

```
number_of_ones = np.count_nonzero(universe == 1)
```

Comment: Извините, а не могли бы привести пример того, как эти команды использовать(куда их вписывать, в if, или цикл?

Comment: @OlehChaika, циклов никаких не надо, при работе с numpy они редко используются.

Comment: Беда в том, что мне нужно посмотреть количество единиц в окрестностях каждой ячейки по очереди, и если единиц больше 3, то присвоить этой ячейке 0. Окрестность это 8 соседних клеток(1 в каждую сторону)

Comment: @OlehChaika, так и задавайте такой вопрос. Я ответил на то, что вы спросили.